# Tabnine not working in Visual Studio 2019 when writing HTML file

Tags: visual-studio-2019, tabnine

When I was editing a HTML file with VS 2019, Tabnine did give me some suggestions, but when I select one of them and hit enter, nothing happens. Neither reinstalling Tabnine nor restarting VS 2019 helps. The weird thing is that Tabnine still functions normally in C# code completion. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have this exact issue. I too would like a solution for this. It's actually quite obstructive because it also prevents me from moving the cursor around the text when it pops up because it's the active window, yet I can't close it without using the mouse to click away from it.